# Placeholder font style is not changing in visualforce

Tags: css, html, placeholder-text

For some reason, placeholder font style is displayed as italic by default instead of regular text and I want to change it to the normal placeholder text.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   font-style: normal;
}
```

The above doesn't seem to work.Can anyone please help with this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Could you please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/320221/edit) your question to provide some more context? Specifically, is this in Visualforce, Lightning Aura or LWC? Additionally could you please update the question with a bit more of just what you are doing - showing the HTML and CSS together so we have a better idea of the problem space?

Comment: I believe you are using Chrome/Opera/Safari based on the code snippet you provided.If you are trying to make these work in other browsers, note that these rules cannot be combined into one selector. They must be declared separately. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487394/how-to-set-the-color-and-font-style-of-placeholder-text/38487528